# Add a custom section to UITableView when working with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: nsfetchedresultscontroller, uitableview

I'm working with `NSFetchedResultsController` to fill one of my `UITableView`s with data grouped into sections. Now I want to add a new section atop all the fetched sections created by data that would not be fetched (I'm creating an additional array for that). Is there a nice way to insert that array without breaking all the nice `NSFetchedResultsController` behavior?

**Update**

What I've tried so far is to manually adjust every use of the `indexPath`. When ever a method (i.e. `-tableView:numbersOfRowsInSection`) get's called I check if it's the first section and if so I would take the data from my array instead of the `NSFetchedResultsController`. If not, I would just create a new `NSIndexPath` with the original `indexPath`'s row and the section - 1 to access the `fetchedResults`. This seems to be a rather naive approach. At least, this does not work for me (yet).

Thanks!
–f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a `UITableViewDataSource` with a mixture of static and dynamic sections. I do it by modifying `NSIndexPath` like you planned. Important is to modify the `NSIndexPath` in the delegate methods of `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`, too:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:kSectionWithAdditionalRowIndex];
    if (newIndexPath) {
        newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row + 1 inSection:kSectionWithAdditionalRowIndex];
    }

    [super controller:controller didChangeObject:anObject atIndexPath:indexPath forChangeType:type newIndexPath:newIndexPath];
}
```

The sample is taken from a subclass of my class [CBUIFetchResultsDataSource.m](https://github.com/chbeer/CBUIKit/blob/master/Classes/CBUIFetchResultsDataSource.m), which is a generic `UITableViewDataSource` powered by a `NSFetchedResultsController`. I had to also overwrite `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`, `-(id)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath` and `-(NSIndexPath*)indexPathForObject:(id)object`.

Comment: Awesome, you were right. I had the delegate methods wrong. Thanks!